# How to grab last two lines from ansible (register stdout) initialization of kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

This is the piece of my playbook file for the question:

```
  - name: Initialize the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm
    command: kubeadm init --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadminit.yaml
    register: init_output

  - name: Copy join command to local file
    local_action: copy content={{ init_output.stdout }} dest="./join-command"
```

Currently join-command contains the entire stdout (30+ lines of text) for content.  What I want to grab is just the last two lines of init_output.stdout instead of the entire output.  I've looked into using index reference (ie. init_output.stdout[#]) but I don't know that the output will always be the same length and I don't know how to use indexes to grab more than one line, but i'm fairly certain that the last two lines will always be the join command.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select last 2 lines from the list `stdout_lines`

```
- local_action: copy content={{ init_output.stdout_lines[-2:] }} dest="./join-command"
```

---

It's possible to format the lines in a block. For example

```
    - local_action:
        module: copy
        content: |
          {{ init_output.stdout_lines[-2] }}
          {{ init_output.stdout_lines[-1] }}
        dest: "./join-command"
```

To append the lines in a loop try

```
    - local_action:
        module: lineinfile
        path: "./join-command"
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: EOF
        create: true
      loop: "{{ init_output.stdout_lines[-2:] }}"
```

Comment: Ok I tried the first option and it gets the content I want but format includes square brackets and quotes and even a comma between the two lines.  

["kubeadm join x.x.x.x:6443 --token y7yaev.9dvwxx6ny4ef8vlq \\", "    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:196a90d11697ee60076c494d55991beea81fe9e196035197bbdf7d4d7901b66d "]

I then tried with stdout instead of stdout_lines and it seems to only grab the last character of stdout...  I'll try the block version next.

Comment: Ah. just realized why using only stdout grabs only 1 character... It's treating every character as an index... so really it's grabbing the last character and the ending space.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this kind of issue and did not want to copy the join command to a local file so I did a set_fact instead this way:

```
- set_fact:
    join_cmd: '{{ init_output.stdout_lines[-2][:-2] }}{{ init_output.stdout_lines[-1] }}'
```

Comment: The `[:-2]` is a bug, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I did this...

```
- name: kubeadm init
  shell: |
    kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint \
    localhost \
    --control-plane-endpoint kube-api.local >> /tmp/run_kube_init.sh
  when: master == "yes"

- name: Get join from master
  fetch:
    src: "/tmp/run_kube_init.sh"
    dest: "/tmp/run_kube_init.sh"
    flat: yes
  when: ansible_hostname == 'k-master'

- name: Add join file to nodes
  copy:
    src: "/tmp/run_kube_init.sh"
    dest: "/tmp/run_kube_init.sh"
  when: master == "no"

- name: Extract join token for nodes
  shell: tail -n +2 /tmp/run_kube_init.sh | head -n -1 | awk '{print $5}' | tail -n 1
  register: JOIN_TOKEN

- set_fact:
    join_token: "{{ JOIN_TOKEN.stdout }}"

- name: join nodes
  shell: |
    kubeadm join kube-api.local:6443 \
    --token {{ JOIN_TOKEN.stdout }} \
    --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification
  when: master == "no"

- name: rm /tmp/run_kube_init.sh
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /tmp/run_kube_init.sh
    state: absent
```